# Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: wordpress

when I click a link on main menu in wordpress, then saying
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at localhost Port 80"

It happen after doing something with slug of a page of main menu

[image]